# Best way to model user 'timeline' of activities in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently building a web-based mini-social network. Like Facebook, each user has sort of a timeline where recent activities are posted. These activities includes status updates, posts to pages, adding new friends and liking pages.

They are modeled separately in the database using these tables with respective columns:

**USER**

- user_id
- firstname
- lastname

**STATUS**

- status_id
- user_id
- content
- time

**POST**

- user_id
- page_id
- content
- time

**FRIEND**

- friend1
- friend2
- status
- time

**LIKE**

- page_id
- user_id
- time

The problem is, I need to display all these activities in reverse chronological order. As you may notice, the tables have a **time** column in them, but how will I do a query of all these activities if these tables have different columns? Any idea on how I'll execute this? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a stored procedure with @user_id as parameter and have the following query within:

```
SELECT status_id AS activity_id, time, "StatusUpdate" AS activity_desc 
FROM STATUS 
WHERE user_id = @user_id
UNION 
SELECT page_id AS activity_id, time, "LikePage" AS activity_desc 
FROM LIKE
WHERE user_id = @user_id
.
.
--Here specify selections from other tables as well
ORDER BY time DESC
```

I hope this gives you a pointer towards how to go about it. Let me know if it was what you were looking for.

Addendum:

The above query returns you a list of activities of different kind sorted in the chronological order. Now with this result in hand in your business logic layer, you can get other details of a  specific activity depending upon its `ACTIVITY_DESC` field by calling stored procedure meant for that specific activity type. Stored Procedure may look as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStatus @status_id INT
AS
SELECT * FROM STATUS
WHERE status_id = @status_id
```

Getting details activity wise would also help in improving performance as details of an activity would be fetched only when it is required to be displayed on a the timeline page.

Comment: Thanks for answering! My problem with this solution is that I have to query the other columns of each tables to display the details of each activity, which is not so efficient.

For example, if **row number 1** in the query result generated by the procedure is for a status update, then I have to query for the contents of the status. Then, if **row number 2** is a post in a page, then I have to query for the page_id and the contents of the post. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I have appended an addendum, please check my solution above.